# How to create a subset (dataset2) from dataset1 in R script

Tags: r, subset, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a dataset1 in AzureML R script

`dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1)`

How to create a subset of dataset1 which has first 5 rows of dataset1 ?

I tried with `dataset2 <- subset(dataset1, 1:5);` but it is not working. How can i do this ?

Then what would be the best way to sort dataset in R script ?

I am new in R script, any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: check it  http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use

```
dataset2 <- dataset[1:5,]
```

if you want to select the first 5 rows.